# Carbon get name of the day

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm creating a date with carbon on laravel, but I havent seen how to get the name of the day  in a string.

```
$date = new Carbon($request->input("mydate"));
$date->day
```

with day I get a numer ,hot to get a string like "Monday"?

Answer (score 4):

See docs https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

```
$date->englishDayOfWeek
```

*Edit*

For get date in spanish you must be do it manually

```
$daysSpanish = [
    0 => 'lunes',
    1 => 'martes',
    2 => 'miércoles',
    3 => 'jueves',
    4 => 'viernes',
    5 => 'sábado',
    6 => 'domingo',
];
$weekday = $daysSpanish[$date->dayOfWeek]
```

Comment: But Ineed the name in spanish

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: I know how to make it manuallu but I would like to know if its posiible in carbon,then I see its not possible

Comment: it is not possible in carbon

Comment: Or you can extend Carbon instance and change `protected static $days `

Comment: It's actually possible to get the Spanish (or other language) day name directly with Carbon: `$date->locale('es')->dayName;`